# Is it wrong to use the word brimming this way?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The day seemed to be brimming with potential.

Is it wrong to use the word brimming this way? I checked this site called Ludwig and didn't find any sentences where "brimming" with used with the word "day".

Comment: Is this a quote, or sentence that you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

The expression is "brimming with potential" is common enough. It is a metaphor. The imagery is of a cup that is filled to the brim with something. It means "has a lot of potential" ("brimming with possibilities" is also used)

Anything that can have potential can be said to be "brimming with potential".  So you can use it to describe a day.

Comment: 'Brimful' is common, also.